# Nifi UpdateRecord processor issues

Tags: apache-nifi

We are using nifi underneath as our ETL application and came across an issue while working on UpdateRecord processor. While we started working on attribute level in Nifi , for eg the flow used to be

```
List File-> Fetch File ->SpliText -> ExtractText -> UpdateAttribute -> AttributestoCSV -> CSVtoORC -> MergeContent ->PutHDFS
```

**In this approach we had the flexibility to use nifi expression language but this template was not performant mainly because of Mergecontent was very slow.** 
Then we switched to the approach of directly updating content using UpdateRecord without splitting the records and not using attributes to update.

Now the issue is that in UpdateRecord processor if I have to use nifi expression language and not DSL (which has limited functions), it creates two problems:

1. I can not create derive fields because `${field.value}` takes an existing column and writes into an existing column only.
2. `${field.value}` only takes one column into consideration, like if I need to concat two columns I cant using expression language, I will have to switch to DSL . **This creates multiple UpdateRecord for me which I am not comfortable with citing the performance.**

Please guide me through this.

Comment: AttributeToCSV -> Merge first. I don't understand why the MergeContent is slow.

Comment: Even I don't understand the same .

Comment: better to discuss one problem per question... are you asking about mergeContent or about UpdateRecord? for selected case please provide more information parameters, what you want to achieve, the actual result, etc

Comment: Can you share more about what the goal is here? If there are limitations to the Record Path API that are holding you back, they may be good candidates for inclusion in 1.12.0 in a few months. Also, you can hit us up on the mailing lists if you want to go more in depth and conversational about this than SO usually allows.

Comment: @daggett . I just wanted to mention the history of the my templates. The current problem is UpdateRecord. If i have to use nifi expression language then i am not able to use more than two fields at the same time.

Comment: @MikeThomsen sure will do that .